# Applescript: Duplicate selection (folder) to desktop and moving the folder to a different location

Tags: finder, applescript, folders

First of, i'm an applescript noob;-)  What I'm asking for is simple but nearly impossible for me to execute. See the script below.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selected_items to selection
    set the defaultPath to path to desktop folder as alias
    duplicate selection to defaultPath

    --I want to take take selection variable that is duplicated to the desktop and move that folder icon to the bottom of my screen.
    set desktop position of selection to {1400, 1200}
end tell
```

Here is the error I get ----> error "Finder got an error: Can’t set desktop position of selection to {1400, 1200}." number -10006 from desktop position of selection

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set desktop position of (selection as alias) to {200, 200}
end tell
```